# C# Pass bitwise operator as parameter

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators

How can I pass a bitwise operator as a parameter to my method? I've read some articles that describes how to pass for example equality operator as a parameter however they implement it in some way and after this pass it with a delegate. In my case I'm not sure how to implement the bitwise operator.

Comment: you cannot overload that operator

Comment: @SergeSemenov According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx, you can indeed overload the bitwise operators.

Comment: @Eris, you are right. I mean, you cannot overload it generic manner similarly to Equals method. My bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Func<>

```
int MyFunc(int input1, int input2, Func<int, int, int> bitOp)
{
    return bitOp(input1, input2);
}
```

Use like this

```
Console.WriteLine(MyFunc(1, 2, (a, b) => a | b));
```

Outputs "3"

Comment: Upvoted. This is using a delegate instance created from an anonymous function. However it is not entirely clear if this is what the asker wants.

Answer (score 5):

Appreciate the answer has already been accepted at this point, but thought I would at least share another possible approach:

```
int result = Bitwise.Operation(1, 2, Bitwise.Operator.OR); // 3
```

Declared as:

```
public static class Bitwise
{
    public static int Operation(int a, int b, Func<int, int, int> bitwiseOperator)
    {
        return bitwiseOperator(a, b);
    }

    public static class Operator
    {
        public static int AND(int a, int b)
        {
            return a & b;
        }

        public static int OR(int a, int b)
        {
            return a | b;
        }
    }
}
```