# JavaScript -- pass a boolean (or bitwise) operator as an argument?

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators, boolean-operations

In C# there are various ways to do this [C# Pass bitwise operator as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36106018/c-sharp-pass-bitwise-operator-as-parameter) specifically the "Bitwise.Operator.OR" object, but can something like this be done in JavaScript? For example:

```
function check(num1, num2, op) {
    return num1 op num2; //just an example of what the output should be like
}

check(1,2, >); //obviously this is a syntax error, but is there some kind of other object or bitwise operator of some kind I can plug into the place of ">" and change the source function somehow?
```

Comment: No there is no way. The only way is to pass a string containing operator and use `eval()` which is not good.

Comment: @MaheerAli `new Function` is better here.

Comment: @Kaiido how would that work?

Comment: @Kaiido `new Function` also uses `eval()`

Comment: @MaheerAli doesn't the terms ">" and ">>" have constructors of some sort just like true and false?

Comment: It'd be repetitive, but you could make an object whose keys are the operators, whose values are a function that you pass the `num1` and `num2` to, which returns the evaluated expression

Comment: @MaheerAli no it doesn't, at least not the evil part: you are not going to the global scope and it is generally better optimised

Comment: @CertainPerformance what would the values for that object look like if there are more than 2 variables

Comment: It would depend on the operator. The only ternary operator I know of in JS is the conditional operator `cond1 ? expr1 : expr2`

Comment: @CertainPerformance I mean for the oject with each key being a different operator -- to cover all operators. What would that look like? 

var operators = {
   ">": (num1, num2) => num1 > num2,
   "<": (num1, num2) => num1 < num2
   /*...etc...*/
}

but how would that work for more than 2 numbers?

Comment: @CertainPerformance don't the operators have some kind of constructor? What are they compiled to?

Comment: I thought the only operator that uses more than 2 expressions is the conditional operator. Maybe `'?:': (cond, expr1, expr2) => cond ? expr1 : expr2`

Comment: @CertainPerformance what if you had an expression 2 < 5 && 8 < 10 && 9 > 2... AKA, the "&&" operator, or "||", or "&", etc..

Comment: @CertainPerformance they did talk about **bitwise operators**, even though they used the `>` one in their example.

Comment: @Kaiido whose "they"

Comment: All the bitwise operators look to accept either two or only one argument. If you have multiple operators, then (using the object example) reference that object multiple times, `check['&&'](check['<'](2, 5), check['<'](8, 10))` etc, something like that

Comment: @CertainPerformance so the only way to write 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 would be using nesting?

Comment: It's not the *only* way, but it's *one* way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a object with keys as operators and values as functions. You will need Bracket Notation to access the functions.

You can use Rest Parameters and `some()` and `every()` for more than two parameters for `&&`,`||`.

For the bitwise operator or `+,-,*,/` multiple values you can use `reduce()`

```js
const check = {
  '>':(n1,n2) => n1 > n2,
  '<':(n1,n2) => n1 < n2,
  '&&':(...n) => n.every(Boolean),
  '||':(...n) => n.some(Boolean),
  '&':(...n) => n.slice(1).reduce((ac,a) => ac & a,n[0])
}

console.log(check['>'](4,6)) //false
console.log(check['<'](4,6)) /true
console.log(check['&&'](2 < 5, 8 < 10, 9 > 2)) //true

console.log(check['&'](5,6,7)  === (5 & 6 & 7))
```

Comment: what if there are more than just 2 numbers

Comment: @bluejayke How there could be more than two numbers in greater than or less than operator?

Comment: @bluejayke You can't have more than two operands for `>` or `<`. If you want more this for `||` and `&&` so see the edited answer.

Comment: OK I guess this is pretty much the answer, can you still explain tho why "Boolean" was passed to n.every? and also how would you do this for bitwise operators, or espeically the "&" operator, which continues to the next expression even if its false, for example?

Comment: @bluejayke `every` method takes a callback. So I passed `Boolean` to it. It will check if all(in first case) or atleast(in second case) are true. `n.every(Boolean)` is same as `n.every(x => x)`

Comment: @bluejayke I don't know much about bitwise operators but. It think you can use `reduce()` for that see the updated answer

Answer (score 2):

You can do the exact same thing suggested by the linked answers:

```
function check(num1, num2, op) {
  return op(num1, num2);
}

// Use it like this
check(3, 7, (x, y) => x > y);
```

You can also create an object that provides all of these operations:

```
const Operators = {
  LOGICAL: {
    AND: (x, y) => x && y,
    OR: (x, y) => x || y,
    GT: (x, y) => x > y,
    // ... etc. ...
  },
  BITWISE: {
    AND: (x, y) => x & y,
    OR: (x, y) => x | y,
    XOR: (x, y) => x ^ y,
    // ... etc. ...
  }
};

// Use it like this
check(3, 5, Operators.BITWISE.AND);
```

Comment: what if there is more than 2 variables per operator, like true && false && true && false etc.....

Comment: Also this seems to be different than the C# function: Bitwise.Operation(1, 2, Bitwise.Operator.OR); // 3, seemingly "Bitwise.Operator.OR" is a constant, not a function

Comment: Fortunately, nesting helps us here: `BITWISE.AND(3, BITWISE.AND(7, BITWISE.AND(12, 93)))` is the same as `3 & 7 & 12 & 93` :-D

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36107908/135978 - In the example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36107908/135978) it's definitely a static method, not a constant.

Comment: Good point, then its just a matter of recursively tracking through it

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
 function binaryOperation( obj1, obj2, operation ) {
     return operation( obj1, obj2 );
 }
 function greaterThan( obj1, obj2 ) {
    return obj1 > obj2 ;
 }
 function lessThan( obj1, obj2 ) {
    return obj1 < obj2 ;
 }
 alert( binaryOperation( 10, 20, greaterThan ) );
 alert( binaryOperation( 10, 20, lessThan ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. But 1 way you can approach this is by doing the following:

```
function evaluate(v1, v2, op) {
    let res = "" + v1 + op + v2;
    return eval(res)
}
console.log(evaluate(1, 2, "+"));
# outputs 3
```

But be careful while passing `args` as they will be evaluated which is dangerous if some hacky code is passed to the function.

Comment: well if you're using eval can't u just eval the entire boolean?